# Proving $0/0$ case of L'Hospital's rule

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

In the proofs of the $0/0$ case of L'Hospital's rule that I have seen so far, if we are interested in determining $$\lim_{x \to a}\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$ and given that $f, g$ are differentiable at $x = a$ and their derivatives are continuous at $x = a$, one always assumes that $f(a) = g(a) = 0$, but isn't the requirement; $$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = \lim_{x \to a}g(x) = 0$$ is enough, meaning that the functions doesn't necessarily have to be defined at this point.

The proof I'm referring to goes as follow:

Given that $f(a) = g(a) = 0$, we know that
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow a} \frac{f^{\prime}(x)}{g^{\prime}(x)}=L
$$
that means we can find a $\delta$ -neighborhood around $a$ such that if $x \in V_{s}(a)$ implies this limit is $\epsilon$ close to $L$. Now, if we apply the GMVT to some points $x, a \in V_{\delta}(a)$, WLOG $x>a$, then we have
$$
\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{g(x)-g(a)}=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{f^{\prime}(c)}{g^{\prime}(c)}
$$
for some $c \in(a, x) \subseteq V_{\delta}(a)$. Since this $c$ is also in $V_{\delta}(a)$, we conclude that
$$
\left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}-L\right|=\left|\frac{f^{\prime}(c)}{g^{\prime}(c)}-L\right|<\epsilon
$$
which proves that $\lim _{x \rightarrow a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim _{x \rightarrow a} \frac{f^{\prime}(x)}{g^{\prime}(x)}=L$

What would one have to change such that the proof is also applicable if the functions $f$ and $g$ are not defined at $x = a$ and we only have $\lim\limits_{x \to a}f(x) = \lim\limits_{x \to a}g(x) = 0$? What would one have to change if $L = \infty$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does L'Hospital's rule require the limit to exist? About the proof.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3727727/why-does-lhospitals-rule-require-the-limit-to-exist-about-the-proof)

Comment: @OliverDiaz no, the answer provided below is what I expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ and/or $g$ are not defined at $x=a$, you may extend them by continuity (say to $f^*$ and $g^*$) by defining $f^*(x)=0$ if $x=a$ and $f^*(x)=f(x)$ otherwise. The proof is the same with $f^*$ and $g^*$ instead of $f$ and $g$.

If $L=\infty$, what you need to change is:

That means that $\forall M>0$ we can find a $\delta$ -neighborhood around $a$ such that if $x \in V_{s}(a)$ implies this ratio is $>M$

and

$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{f^{\prime}(c)}{g^{\prime}(c)}>M$$

Comment: and for $L = \infty$ it also stays the same?

Comment: practically nothing changes, except that you have to work with neighborhoods of $\infty$ instead of neighborhoods of $L$

Comment: ok, thanks a lot!

Comment: What would I have to adjust if $a = \infty$? Just choose a $\delta$ s.t. for all $x > \delta$ we get into an epsilon region of $0$?

Comment: If I remember well, when $a=\infty$ one should make the change of variable $y=1/x$

Comment: but doesn't that change the limit completely?

Comment: No, it doesn't. See [Limit of Composite Function](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Limit_of_Composite_Function)